# In ruby on rails how do I pass an array as a series of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, rails-activerecord

I have a simple query that I'm attempting to construct.

I want to pass in parameters to the query.

```
Product.where('id = ?', 1)
```

Easy as right.. 
What to do if the field list and the values are arrays

```
fields = ['id = ? ', 'type_id = ?', 'brand_id = ?']
values = [1, 1, 1]
Product.where(fields.join(' and '), values)  #does not compute, does not compute!
```

Anyone know how to pass in the values for a parametrized query?

Comment: FYI: prepared statement !== parametrized query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `*` to convert an array into a parameter list:

```
fields = ['id = ?','type_id = ?','brand_id = ?']
values = [1, 1, 1]
Product.where(fields.join(' and '), *values)
```